# How to list all the failed tasks in Airflow using Data Profiling --> Ad Hoc Query

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG which runs every 4 hours in a day. Every day the first run of the day fails, while the remaining runs pass successfully. The Recent Task's give me all task as passed. But when I click the DAG, I can see the first day of the run as failed from the Tree View.

How can I get the list of all the failed run/tasks for particular DAG from Data Profiling, as I dont want to modify anything in production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Data Profiling** -> **Adhoc Query** -> **airflow_Db** and then execute the following query:

```
 Select * from task_instance where state="failed" && dag_id="your_dag_id"
```

It will list out all the task of that particular **dag_id** which is failed.

If you want all the **task_id** of a particular **dag_id** which got failed, execute the below query:

```
 Select * from task_instance where state="failed" && dag_id="your_dag_id" && task_id="your_task_id"
```

Well like wise you can perform any query, you can see all the filed which is present in the task_instance by querying `select * from task_instance`

Comment: Data Profiling was removed from Airflow 2.0.0 for security concerns. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65813718/733092