# Can't see Data profiling menu

Tags: airflow

I have installed the `airflow 1.10.12` version using `pip`. However, I am not able to see the data profiling menu.

I checked my config file, and it's has secure_mode as false.

```
# If set to False enables some unsecure features like Charts and Ad Hoc Queries.
# In 2.0 will default to True.
secure_mode = False
```

[image]

do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new RBAC Airflow UI (which is the only UI from 2.0.0) does not support Data Profiling or Ad-hoc Query:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#breaking-changes

> Due to security concerns, the new webserver will no longer support the features in the Data Profiling menu of old UI, including Ad Hoc Query, Charts, and Known Events.